# Create a tuple in Python 3 with string and number

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have a object in python like below

```
contributor_detail=contributorId+ ',' +contentFileName+','+productPriority
output =
CSFBW23_1194968,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,10
CSFBW23_1194969,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,11
CSFBW23_1194970,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,13
```

Apology if question was unclear
I will try to reframe it again here ,This is how i am making an array and then need to make tuple to sort .

```
for record in event['Records']:
        #pull the body out & json load it
        jsonmaybe=(record["body"])
        jsonmaybe=json.loads(jsonmaybe)
        jsonmaybe1=(jsonmaybe["Message"])
        jsonmaybe1=json.loads(jsonmaybe1)
        
        #now the normal stuff works
        bucket_name = jsonmaybe1["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        print(bucket_name)
        key=jsonmaybe1["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        print(key)
        
        s3_clientobj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
        s3_clientdata = s3_clientobj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        employee_dict = json.loads(s3_clientdata)
        contributorId=employee_dict['Research']['Product']['@productID']
        contentFileName=employee_dict['Research']['Product']['Content']['Resource']['Name']
        productPriority=employee_dict['Research']['Product']['@productPriority']
        
        print("contributorId---------------"+contributorId)
        print("contentFileName---------------"+contentFileName)
        print("productPriority---------------"+productPriority)
        
        contributor_detail=contributorId +','+contentFileName+','+productPriority
        unsorted_contributors.append(contributor_detail)
```

I want to create a tuple out of it and add multiple object to that tuple .

```
Output i am getting now 
['CSFBW23_1194968,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,6', 'CSFBW23_1194968,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,7', 'CSFBW23_1194968,CSFBW23_1194968.pdf,9']

Expected output 
[("CSFBW23_1194968","CSFBW23_1194968.pdf",6),("CSFBW23_1194968","CSFBW23_1194968.pdf",7),("CSFBW23_1194968","CSFBW23_1194968.pdf",9)]
```

I need tuple in above so that  it can be sorted based on 3rd item in tuple which is number .

```
sorted_contributors.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
```

Please help to create such format in loop

Comment: I don't see the issue? What is the problem?

Comment: @theherk i am not able to form the correct format .it gets created like array and not tuple

Comment: is the list of tuples available to you? what is the source of the data that you want to convert to tuples? what is the format of this source? For example do you have a list of `contributorId` and other such fields?

Comment: I am parsing json and extracting three element and then need to make tuple like mentioned in the  the question.

Comment: @AtharvThakur you will get a tuple if you use `contributor_detail=(contributorId,contentFileName,productPriority)` instead of `contributor_detail=contributorId+ ',' +contentFileName+','+productPriority`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like you just need to stop making `contributor_detail` and string as you are with `contributorId+ ',' +contentFileName+','+productPriority`. Assuming those values are strings and an int, you are joining them as a string with `,`. It really isn't very clear what you're after, but I suspect, what you want is:

```py
conributor_detail = contributorId, contentFileName, productPriority
```

That yields a tuple, from which you can make a list.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

contrib1 = "CSFBW23_1194968", "CSFBW23_1194968.pdf", 10
contrib2 = "CSFBW23_1194969", "CSFBW23_1194968.pdf", 11
contrib3 = "CSFBW23_1194970", "CSFBW23_1194968.pdf", 13

contributors = [contrib1, contrib2, contrib3]
sorted_contributors = sorted(contributors, key=itemgetter(2))
print(sorted_contributors)
```

Output:

```
[('CSFBW23_1194968', 'CSFBW23_1194968.pdf', 10), ('CSFBW23_1194969', 'CSFBW23_1194968.pdf', 11), ('CSFBW23_1194970', 'CSFBW23_1194968.pdf', 13)]
```

A simplified clarification of your issue:

```
# what you are doing (incorrect):

In [1]: contrib1 = "thingB"+","+"thingA"+","+"1"
In [2]: contrib2 = "thingC"+","+"thingD"+","+"2"
In [3]: print([contrib1, contrib2])
['thingB,thingA,1', 'thingC,thingD,2']

# what you really want is:

In [4]: contrib1 = "thingB", "thingA", 1
In [5]: contrib2 = "thingC", "thingD", 2
In [6]: print([contrib1, contrib2])
[('thingB', 'thingA', 1), ('thingC', 'thingD', 2)]
```

Comment: when we create an array from tuples it appends double quotes at start and end of the string

Comment: @AtharvThakur: What do you mean? Quotes indicate a values is a string in python.

Comment: I have updated the question with my complete function ..I am sorry if i have confused you .But i am facing issue creating tuple itself with proper quotes .I will undo the accepted answer for now .

Comment: @AtharvThakur: This answer points out both the issue and the resolution. When you do `contributor_detail=contributorId +','+contentFileName+','+productPriority`, you are setting `contributor_detail` to a string made up of `contributorId` then `,` then `contentFileName`... etc. What you want is `contributor_detail = contributorId, contentFileName, productPriority`. That give a tuple.

Comment: @AtharvThakur: Please see the section I added to my answer for a simplified explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This will create proper format

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(contributorId)
my_list.append(contentFileName)
my_list.append(bucket_name)
my_list.append(key)
my_list.append(int(productPriority))

unsorted_contributors.append(my_list)
```

Concatenation is creating a format mismatch so create a list and append that will should work